# Annotiation combinbation of @ConfigurationProperties @DefaultValue @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: spring-boot

I got a class (more specifically, a record) MyappProperties that is annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` that has a lot of configuration options.
The are several inner classes (more specifically, inner records) in the class that hold configuration options that are specific to a certain functionality of my application.
One of the configuration options, `writerImplementation`, within one of the inner classes has a default value annotated with `@DefaultValue`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public record MyappProperties(
...
  @DefaultValue ConfigForJob configForJob
  ) {
  ...
  public record ConfigForJob (
  @DefaultValue("MongoTemplate") String writerImplementation
  ) {
  ...
  }
}
```

I want to use the value of the configuration option `writerImplementation` to conditionally make a Spring Bean available within the application context depending on the value of the configuration option:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myapp.config-for-job.writer-implementation", havingValue = "MongoTemplate")
public Tasklet mongoTemplateTasklet(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
...
}

@Bean
@Autowired
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myapp.config-for-job.writer-implementation", havingValue = "MongoRepository")
public Tasklet mongoRepositoryTasklet(MongoRepository mongoRepository) {
...
}
```

This, however, does not to work. The application fails to start with the message that there isn't a Bean `mongoTemplateTasklet` available. If I manually set the value for the property with the key `myapp.config-for-job.writer-implementation` (that is, by putting it in application.properties or command line with `-Dmyapp.config-for-job.writer-implementation=MongoTemplate`) it works fine.

So it seems like the default value set via the `@DefaultValue` annotation is not taken up by Spring (or not taken up in time to be available for evaluating the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation).

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

> So it seems like the default value set via the `@DefaultValue` annotation is not taken up by Spring (or not taken up in time to be available for evaluating the `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation).

That's correct. Both `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@ConditionalOnProperty` use the application context's `Environment` as the source of property values and one has no effect on the other.

When binding to a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean, `@DefaultValue` is used to specify a value when the environment does not contain a value for the property. It only applies to this specific binding of the property.

> putting it in application.properties or command line with `-Dmyapp.config-for-job.writer-implementation=MongoTemplate`) it works fine

This works because you have set the value `MongoTemplate` so that it appears in the application context's environment. It can then be found by both `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@ConditionalOnProperty`.

You may want to use `matchIfMissing` on `@ConditionalOnProperty`:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "myapp.config-for-job.writer-implementation", havingValue = "MongoTemplate", matchIfMissing = true)
```

This will cause the condition to match if `myapp.config-for-job.writer-implementation` has been set to `MongoTemplate` or if it hasn't been set at all.